# Return matching values instead of boolean

Tags: r

Consider:

```
chars <- c("A", "B", "C")

string <- c("B", "C")

chars[!(chars %in% string)]
```

So, I want to get the char(s) which is(are) not in string.
The code works, but I feel like it's kind of inconvenient.

Is there a function in R which returns the actual value directly, instead of evaluating TRUE/FALSE and then indexing?

Comment: Perhaps `setdiff(chars, string)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As akrun mentioned you want to use

```
setdiff(chars, string)
```

more generally, the help page for setdiff is the same than union and other useful and I feel underused functions to perform operations on sets such as

```
intersect()
```

Which more directly answers the phrasing of your initial question.